# Proof that $A^C\cap A = \varnothing$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

*Proof.* Consider $x\in A \overset{\text{def}}{\Longrightarrow} x \notin A^C$. Therefore $A\nsubseteq A^C$.

Consider also $x\in A^C \overset{\text{def}}{\Longrightarrow} x \notin A$. Therefore  $A^C\nsubseteq A$.

Since $A^C\nsubseteq A$ and $A\nsubseteq A^C$  we prove that $A^C \cap A = \varnothing$.

---

I have a simple question: does my proof contain errors?

EDIT:

I think I have got it now.

*Proof*. Let $A \subseteq \Omega$.

Assume there is an element such that $x \in A\cap A^C$. This is equivalent to $x\in A$ and $x\in A^C. $

Since $x \in A \overset{\text{def}}{\Longrightarrow}x\notin A^C$, there exists no $x$ such that $x\in A$ simultaneously as $x\in A^C$.

Therefore, $\nexists x: x\in A \wedge x\in A^C$ and $A\cap A^C=\varnothing$.

Comment: In your title you mention $A'$ but nowhere do you mention it in your body. I assume you mean $A'=A^c$. Your proof contains errors assuming this is what you mean because $A \not\subset B$ and $B \not\subset A$ doesn't imply $A \cap B = \emptyset$. For example, the nonnegative numbers and the nonpositive numbers do not contain each other, but 0 is in both sets.

Comment: Um.. why does $X \not \subset Y$ and $Y\not \subset X$ imply $X\cap Y =\emptyset$?  Is that an axiom?  A definition?  I think for a proof about basic concepts one has to be extra precise about definitions.  Frankly I have to wonder about anyone being *asked* to "prove" this.  It is essentially definition.  $A^c$ is defined to be the set of precisely the elements that are not contained in $A$ so there can't be any elements in both.

Comment: I've made an edit. I keep the previous mistakes as reference.

Comment: It might help your proof to begin it with a clear, self-contained definition of $A^C$, e.g., "If $A$ is a set, its *complement* is the set $A^C=\{x: x\not\in A\}$."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude $X\cap Y = \varnothing $ from $X\nsubseteq Y$ and $Y\nsubseteq X$ (take, for instance, $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{b,c\}$). That being said, your first two lines are true, and any one of your two implications can be used to deduce that no $x$ can be in both $A$ and its complement.

Answer (score 1):

You state that $A^C \not\subseteq A$ and $A \not\subseteq A^C$ implies $A^C \cap A = \emptyset$.  This is not true.  For example, $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{3,4,5\}$ have the property $A \not\subseteq B$ and $B \not\subseteq A$, but their intersection is $\{3\}$, which is nonempty.
For a correct proof of this fact, we need to show that there exist *no* elements in the intersection, not just that they are not subsets of each other.
To this end, suppose there is an element $x$, in $A^C \cap A$.  Since $x$ in $A^C \cap A$, then $x \in A^C$, by definition of $\cap$.  But since $x \in A^C$, then $x \not\in A$, by the definition of the complement.  So $x \in A^C \cap A$ implies that $x \not\in A$.  If $x \not\in A$, then $x \not\in A^C \cap A$.  But this contradicts the assumption that $x \in A \cap A^C$.  Thus, there cannot exist any elements in $A^C \cap A$, which means $A^C \cap A = \emptyset$.